# To append values to an existing csv file without overwriting it

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am new to PowerShell scripting. I am trying to write a simple program as follows:

```
$obj=New-Object PSObject
$obj | Add-Member Noteproperty -Name EID -value "E566865"
$obj | Add-Member Noteproperty -Name Email -value "fname.lname"
$obj | Add-Member Noteproperty -Name MVP -value $True
$obj | export-csv D:\sample.csv
```

Where I am writing the output to CSV file I would like to create one more similar object like this and write that output to the same file without overwriting it. Please suggest some suitable ways.

Answer (score 0):

Add the -Append flag to the Export-Csv cmdlet.

For instance:

$obj | export-csv -Path D:\sample.csv -Append